# Using static resources inside a jar library (to be used in Android)

Tags: java, android, jar, resources, classpath

I am developing a plain java library (jar), which contains some static files, which I put to `src/main/resources`. These static files are used to execute an algorithm and return processed data to the user.

```
public String getStringFromFile(String fileName) {
    String text = "";

    try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        text = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        scanner.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return text;
}
```

So far so good. However, when I try to use this library/method in an Android project I get:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.net.URL.getFile()' on a null object reference

I want my static resource files to be published with the library. Am I doing something wrong? Any thoughts?

Comment: `classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile()` is useless. It should return to you the same value as `fileName`, and that will not point to anything that you can use. You can try `getResourceAsStream()` and see if it works, but this sort of JAR resource is rarely used on Android (if ever).

Comment: @CommonsWare ``getResourceAsStream()`` would not work either - it returns null. This is really disappointing as I don't want to create a *.aar just because android cannot find static files on the classpath :(

Comment: I tried to decompile the resulting apk and the file I am trying to load is there. Strangely, Android puts it to the ``unknown`` folder in the root directory..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I think I have solved this. Following this [article](http://vourkosa.github.io/android/2016/04/06/Sharing-code-among-Android-applications-Including-and-reading-images-from-jar-files.html) I created a `res` directory in the root of my jar module (on the same level as the `src` directory) and put my files there (`helloworld.json`). Then added this to `build.gradle`:

```
jar {
  into('resourcez') {
    from 'res'
  }
}
```

Using this helper function (inside the jar lib) and `getResourceAsStream()` I get the contents of my resource files:

```
public String getModelFromStream(String fileName) {
    final String classpath = "resourcez/";
    ClassLoader classLoader = DexiModelLoader.class.getClassLoader();
    InputStream resourceAsStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);

    if (resourceAsStream == null)
        resourceAsStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(classpath + fileName);

    if (resourceAsStream == null)
        return "error";

    Scanner s = new Scanner(resourceAsStream).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```

After this I simply call `getStringFromStream("helloworld.json")` or `getStringFromStream("resourcez/helloworld.json")` in my android app and voilà!